# How to validate or verify JWT Signature?

Tags: java, security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to validate JWT token in Java.How to validate or verify JWT Signature of JWT token?

Answer (score 4):

You can use JWT library from Spring Security available at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt/1.0.1.RELEASE.

Class org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper has a static method which allows you to parse the JWT token and verify its signature.

Comment: thanks a lot.you saved my time.But using this jar it's not validating token against expiration time

Comment: That's correct, the library doesn't interpret any claims contained inside the token (i.e. it doesn't try to understand what's the content of the token), this implies that it also doesn't check any expiration. Also, your question was only about verification of signatures. It is trivial to check the expiration in your own code and is probably preferred, as the claim "exp" can be encoded in different ways (e.g. include or skip milliseconds).

Comment: Is there also a library for Java EE?