# Secure Java Web API with OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth

it's quite simple to secure/protect an ASP.NET Web API with OWIN (Katana). Now, I'm looking for a Java library that offers OWIN-similar features, so that I can secure my Java-based Web APIs. Only GET and POST requests with a Bearer token in the header are allowed, otherwise a HTTP 401 should be returned. Therefore the library should be able to verify the Bearer token.

Any hint, link, reference, etc. is highly appreciated. Thanks!
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

[BearerToken.parse(String)](http://authlete.github.io/authlete-java-common/com/authlete/common/web/BearerToken.html#parse(java.lang.String)) in [authlete-java-common](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-java-common) covers the three ways to extract an access token described in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) (Bearer Token Usage).

```java
// Case 1:
// Extract an access token from 'Authorization' HTTP header.

// The value of 'Authorization' HTTP header.
String authorization = ...;

// Extract an access token from 'Authorization' HTTP header.
String accessToken = BearerToken.parse(authorization);
```

```java
// Case 2:
// Extract an access token from the entity body of a POST request.

// Entity body formatted in 'application/x-www-url-encoded'.
String body = ...;

// Extract an access token.
String accessToken = BearerToken.parse(body);
```

```java
// Case 3:
// Extract an access token from the query string of a GET request.

// Query string.
String query = ...;

// Extract an access token.
String accessToken = BearerToken.parse(query);
```

Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.authlete</groupId>
    <artifactId>authlete-java-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It wouldn't take much time even if you implemented the same thing from scratch, though.

Source code -> [BearerToken.java](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-java-common/blob/master/src/main/java/com/authlete/common/web/BearerToken.java)

Comment: Thanks Takahiko. Is there any library that helps for example to validate the token? There is the JwtSecurityTokenHandler class in .NET, used by OWIN. So something similar in Java would be really helpful as well. :-)

Comment: Ok, found something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081693/how-to-validate-or-verify-jwt-signature.